# How to parse req.body in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am passing 10.0.0.12 value in axios get from react side to node , When I am trying to print req.body on node side it displays [object,object] how to get value from object?

This How I am sending req:
     axios

```
  .get("/ashjg/GetTfsItem",
       {BuildNumber:event.target.value[event.target.value.length-1].BuildNumber},{headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}},
    )
     .then(response => {
         console.log("responce data"+response.data);
       if(response.status==200){
           this.setState({TfsItemdata : response.data});
       }else{
           this.setState({errorMessage:"Data Not Available "})
       }
     })
     .catch(error => {
       this.setState({errorMessage:"Data Not Available for Crash Id  "})
     });

    }
```

Node Js Side :

```
router.get("/GetTfsItem",function(req,res,next){
    console.dir( "Inside GetTfsItem " + Jreq.body );
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: console.log(req.body) or console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))

Comment: Tried but not working

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. What are you using in the backend? Express?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **body-parser** like this:

```js
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 
var app = express()
 
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
 
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

Remember you need to install body-parser:

```js
npm i body-parser
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using `express.js` then you can do it like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/handle',function(request,response){
var query1=request.body.var1;
var query2=request.body.var2;
});
```